# Color of drawInRect:withAttributes:

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

Is was trying to fix some warnings in an iOS app and changed the update of this:

```
[[self text] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSize]];
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
```

to this:

```
[[self text] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSize]}];
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
```

However now the color of the text is black... How can I fix this?

Comment: BTW - the old way wouldn't work either since you needed to set the color before drawing the text.

Comment: It was working before, not sure why... it was built for iOS 4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the color to the attributes:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSize], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] };
[[self text] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
```

No need to set the color the old way with this approach.